# Mac M1 compatible docker image

Tags: m1

Has someone managed to build an m1 compatible solana docker image ?

I tried to build one but I didn't succeed

I need to run the `solana-test-validator` as part of a docker stack to run automated testing during development on my mac

The official amd64 image complains about missing cpu instructions

I tried using this Dockerfile with `platform: linux/amd64`

```
FROM debian:bullseye

RUN apt update && \
    apt-get install -y bzip2 libssl-dev wget curl build-essential

RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | \
    sh -s -- --default-toolchain stable -y && \
    /root/.cargo/bin/rustup update beta && \
    /root/.cargo/bin/rustup update nightly

ENV PATH=/root/.cargo/bin:$PATH

WORKDIR /build

ENV solana_version=1.10.27

RUN wget https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/archive/refs/tags/v${solana_version}.tar.gz

RUN tar -xf v${solana_version}.tar.gz

WORKDIR /build/solana-${solana_version}

RUN ./scripts/cargo-install-all.sh .
```

But it hangs after a `rustc` `SIGSEGV` with

```
 => => #   process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name regex_syntax --edition=2018 /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/regex-syntax-0.6.25/src/lib.rs --error-
 => => # format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no --cfg 'feature="default"'
 => => #  --cfg 'feature="unicode"' --cfg 'feature="unicode-age"' --cfg 'feature="unicode-bool"' --cfg 'feature="unicode-case"' --cfg 'feature="unicode-gencat"' --cfg 'feature="unicode-p
 => => # erl"' --cfg 'feature="unicode-script"' --cfg 'feature="unicode-segment"' -C metadata=be627418f4c93248 -C extra-filename=-be627418f4c93248 --out-dir /build/solana-1.10.27/target/
 => => # release/deps -L dependency=/build/solana-1.10.27/target/release/deps --cap-lints allow` (signal: 11, SIGSEGV: invalid memory reference)
 => => # warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

For information, I can build solana from source on the m1 out of docker

Answer (score 2):

I managed to build it using this Dockerfile and `linux/arm64` platform

It seems to work at first but it doesn't finalize slots and only the first few transaction works (for example one or two airdrop work then any subsequent one fail with "unable to confirm transaction")

I tried the same Dockerfile in a linux host with platform `linux/amd64` and it seems to fully work

```
FROM debian:bullseye

RUN apt update && \
    apt-get install -y bzip2 libssl-dev wget curl build-essential

RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | \
    sh -s -- --default-toolchain stable -y && \
    /root/.cargo/bin/rustup update beta && \
    /root/.cargo/bin/rustup update nightly

ENV PATH=/root/.cargo/bin:$PATH

WORKDIR /build

ENV solana_version=1.10.27

RUN wget https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/archive/refs/tags/v${solana_version}.tar.gz

RUN tar -xf v${solana_version}.tar.gz

WORKDIR /build/solana-${solana_version}

RUN apt update && \
    apt-get install -y pkg-config libudev-dev cmake libclang-dev

RUN ./scripts/cargo-install-all.sh .

# RPC JSON
EXPOSE 8899/tcp
# RPC pubsub
EXPOSE 8900/tcp
# entrypoint
EXPOSE 8001/tcp
# (future) bank service
EXPOSE 8901/tcp
# bank service
EXPOSE 8902/tcp
# faucet
EXPOSE 9900/tcp
# tvu
EXPOSE 8000/udp
# gossip
EXPOSE 8001/udp
# tvu_forwards
EXPOSE 8002/udp
# tpu
EXPOSE 8003/udp
# tpu_forwards
EXPOSE 8004/udp
# retransmit
EXPOSE 8005/udp
# repair
EXPOSE 8006/udp
# serve_repair
EXPOSE 8007/udp
# broadcast
EXPOSE 8008/udp
# tpu_vote
EXPOSE 8009/udp

ENV PATH=/build/solana-${solana_version}/bin:$PATH

ENTRYPOINT [ "solana-test-validator" ]
```